# PXProcessing SetError not showing in UI Grid

Tags: acumatica

This my process screen:
[image]
as you can see it throws errors but it doesnt indicate the error mark on the grid.
After clicking the process button, it just unchecks the checkbox in my records

i want the grid to be like this(with the red 'x' mark):

[image]

this is my graph :

```
public PXCancel<PayrollFilter> Cancel;

    public PXSetup<PayrollSetup> PayrollSetup;

    public PXFilter<PayrollFilter> Filter;

    [PXFilterable]
    public PXFilteredProcessingJoin<PayrollEmployeeProcess, PayrollFilter,
                                InnerJoin<EPEmployee,
                                    On<PayrollEmployee.employeeID, Equal<EPEmployee.bAccountID>>,
                                InnerJoin<Branch,
                                     On<EPEmployee.parentBAccountID, Equal<Branch.bAccountID>>>>,
                                Where<PayrollEmployee.payPeriodID, Equal<Current<PayrollFilter.payPeriodID>>,
                                And<Branch.branchID, Equal<Current<AccessInfo.branchID>>>>> EmployeePayrollProcess;



    #region Constructor
    public PayrollProcess()
    {
        PayrollSetup setup = PayrollSetup.Current;

        EmployeePayrollProcess.SetSelected<PayrollEmployeeProcess.selected>();

        EmployeePayrollProcess.SetProcessDelegate(delegate (List<PayrollEmployeeProcess> employees)
        {
            if (Filter.Current == null) return;

            var payPeriod = Filter.Current.PayPeriodID ?? 0;
            var payrollPeriod = Filter.Current.PayrollPeriodID ?? 0;

            if (payPeriod == 0 || payrollPeriod == 0) return;

            PXLongOperation.StartOperation(this, delegate ()
            {
                bool errorOccured = false;
                foreach (PayrollEmployeeProcess employee in employees)
                {

                    PayrollRegisterEntry graph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<PayrollRegisterEntry>();
                    try
                    {

                        graph.ProcessPayroll(employee, payPeriod, payrollPeriod);
                        PXProcessing<PayrollEmployeeProcess>.SetInfo("Employee processed");

                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        errorOccured = true;
                        //employees.IndexOf(employee), 
                        PXProcessing<PayrollEmployeeProcess>.SetError(ex);
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        graph.Clear();
                    }
                }
                if (errorOccured) throw new PXException("At least one employee was not processed.");
            });

        });
        // EmployeePayrollProcess.
    }`
```

can anyone can help me? I'm using Acumatica 6

Comment: There might be some BatchUpdate setting in the page and I typically see the processing of records on the process pages call a static method as the processing call which has helped resolve some issues for me in the past.

Comment: should I use BatchUpdate on the grid settings? I already set the SyncPosition settings

Comment: I always use release IN documents as my go to for an example in a processing page. (Page IN501000 / Graph INDocumentRelease). It uses BatchUpdate="true". Note that the process calls a static method called ReleaseDoc. Try to implement something similar. I have had issues with the objects being passed into the static call too. Its a little picky to get the processing icons to show, but use this graph as your example and you should be able to get it working

Answer (score 1):

Throwing an exception in Acumatica sets the error in the header. To set a Row or Field level error you need to set/raise it. There's a few ways to set/raise errors, what they have in common is that they don't use the 'throw' keyword.

For a processing screen with a filter, use the following syntax to raise the error:

```
PXFilteredProcessing<GridDetailDAC, GridFilterDAC>.SetError(rowIndex, new PXSetPropertyException("Error Message", PXErrorLevel.RowError));
```

Processing screen without filter:

```
PXProcessing.SetError(rowIndex, new PXException("Error Message"));
```

Comment: this might i've been looking for, i've been following the t200 tutorial but it didnt work, I'll try your solution this might work thank you

Comment: You're already doing it for SetInfo, the pattern is similar for SetError. There's a few variant, experiment a bit with it and choose the one which works best in your context.

Comment: Maybe its on the GridSettings, I've already set the 'SyncPosition ' to True.

Comment: Are you still throwing an exception? SetInfo is in the code from your question, should be the same for SetError.